# Use custom function in default of schema?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a schema like this:

```
   new mongoose.Schema({
     name: String,
     uniq: {type: String, default: Math.random() + "a"},
   })
```

I cannot get random but only `null` for uniq field

Is it possible to use custom function in default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
uniq: {type: String, default: function(){ return Math.random() + "a"; } }
```

Check [mongoose document](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/defaults.html).